# mount command fstab in linux

Tags: linux, mount, cifs, fstab

i have a command to manually mount windows shares into my linux system. Unfortunately the paths are not mounted when the system reboots. How can I add the path to the fstab table ?

```
 mount -t cifs -o user=myuser,domain=ad.myad.com //path/to/Software/bundles /mysoftware
```

The problem is I still have a password which has to be entered as soon as the command is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the online manual for the specific section on mounting cifs file systems and you'll find an option to store the credentials in a external file so you won't have to add them to the world readable /etc/fstab and can keep those private: [`man mount.cifs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs)

> **`credentials=/path/filename`**
>   specifies a file `/path/filename` that contains a username and/or password and optionally the name of the workgroup. The format of the file is:
>
> ```
> username=value
> password=value
> domain=value
> ```
>
> This is preferred over having passwords in plaintext in a shared file, such as `/etc/fstab`. Be sure to protect any credentials file properly.

The /etc/fstab entry will then look something like :

```
//path/to/Software/bundles /mysoftware cifs credentials=/path/filename,_netdev,other,options 0 0
```